# MS Access Connectionstring problem C#

Tags: c#, ms-access, connection-string, ms-access-2007

I have the following code

```
mycon=new SqlConnection();
mycon.ConnectionString="'Provider =Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0';Data Source='G:\\Abbriviations\\Abbriviations\\App_Data\\abbreviations.accdb'";

myds=new DataSet();
mytable = new DataTable("Abbriviations");
myds.Tables.Add(mytable);
myadap=new SqlDataAdapter();
```

I am getting the following error.

**Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0.**

Can you please guide me the correct connectionstring for this.

Thanks
Edit

```
public class dataManipulationClass
    {
        public OleDbConnection mycon;
        public DataSet myds;
        public DataTable mytable;
        public SqlDataAdapter myadap;
        public OleDbCommand mycomm;     

        public bool ManupulateData()
        {
            mycon = new OleDbConnection();          
            mycon.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=G:\\Abbriviations\\Abbriviations\\App_Data\\abbreviations.accdb";

            myds=new DataSet();
            mytable = new DataTable("Abbriviations");
            myds.Tables.Add(mytable);
            myadap=new SqlDataAdapter();

            mycomm=new OleDbCommand();
            mycomm.CommandType=CommandType.Text;
            mycomm.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Abbriviations";
            mycomm.Connection=mycon;
            myadap.SelectCommand=mycomm;

            return true;
        }
    }
```

Now i am getting the following error at mycommm.

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand' to 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand'
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things:

1. You are using the wrong connection object; `SqlConnection` is for communicating with SQL Server databases, while you are trying to talk to an MS Access database. Try using an `OleDbConnection` instead. This also means that you should use an `OleDbDataAdapter` instead of an `SqlDataAdapter`.
2. The string looks a bit odd with extra quotation marks and spaces.

Try this instead:

```
mycon=new OleDbConnection();
mycon.ConnectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=G:\\Abbriviations\\Abbriviations\\App_Data\\abbreviations.accdb";
// and then the rest of your code
```

As a side note, [connectionstrings.com](http://connectionstrings.com/) is a great resource for this kind of info (there is a page for [Access connectionstrings](http://connectionstrings.com/access-2007)).

Comment: Ah, now I see it, you are using an `SqlConnection`, which is for SQL Server databases, you should use `OleDbConnection`. Will update my answer.

Comment: @Tassadaque: You should use `OleDbDataAdapter` instead of `SqlDataAdapter`.